# How to fix amplify pull issue -> local setup

Tags: aws-amplify

I am trying to use amplify authentication with my development. I have configured the staging environment on the AWS console, and I currently am trying to setup locally on my PC.

The command I was supposed to key into the terminal is:

```
amplify pull --appId dxxxxxxxxxxx --envName staging
```

And this is the result:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx>amplify pull --appId dxxxxxxxxxxx --envName staging
Found whitespace in your key name (use quotes to include) at line 2,8 >>><<<<<<< HEAD
  "ver ...
Error: Found whitespace in your key name (use quotes to include) at line 2,8 >>><<<<<<< HEAD
  "ver ...
    at error (C:\snapshot\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:41:11)
    at keyname (C:\snapshot\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:157:76)
    at object (C:\snapshot\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:353:15)
    at legacyRootValue (C:\snapshot\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:428:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\node_modules\hjson\lib\hjson-parse.js:454:23)
    at Function.parse (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-cli-core\lib\jsonUtilities.js:91:22)
    at Function.readJson (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-cli-core\lib\jsonUtilities.js:47:32)
    at StateManager.getData (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-cli-core\lib\state-manager\stateManager.js:215:56)
    at StateManager.getProjectConfig (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-cli-core\lib\state-manager\stateManager.js:95:25)
    at Object.checkProjectConfigVersion (C:\snapshot\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\lib\project-config-version-check.js:33:63)
```

Anyone has any idea what did I do wrong and how do I fix it? Many thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Check if there is any unresolved conflicts after your last git merge.
There is a chance that your code had tabs and after the merge it is getting treated as whitespace.

Comment: Hi, I've checked that but I don't see any unresolved conflicts. :(

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a conflict under `amplify/.config` that directory by default is not displayed in directory listings, (i.e. listing using the `ls` command or in your IDE). Check that out and see if it doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a merge conflict.  While performing the merge I staged the changes with conflicts then tried to blow those changes up with an amplify pull.  I had to finish the merge to API and stage it before amplify pull would not error.

Again, just saving the merge changes did not allow me to pull. I had to stage those changes as well.